# Html structure for images inside two div

Tags: css, html

[image]

I think the picture will explain the question better.
I need div1 as a background for an image. The image can have different sizes. 
Any ideas how to make it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/fgshJ/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="div2">
    <div id="div1">
        <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRi-8XnnXwAZmz_5R5LHRHMNlnYYHCP4WqRdu6vhf_ru8wLK9XB3IrNrwix" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div2 {
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
}

#div1 {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: Thx Smamatti. display: inline-block; this is what i needed :)